# Windows 7 backup files to Dropbox

Tags: windows-7, backup, dropbox

I'm using Windows 7 Ultimate and it has the option to keep my backup files to the network. But I can't understand what I should write on network location box. I want to use my Dropbox for backup.

So on Dropbox I made a folder named my_backup and assume I have write the path as `www.dropbox.com/my_backup` and then on the username and password box I use my Dropbox credentials. But it didn't work. Should this work, and if so why isn't it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That dialog is for selecting a backup drive currently on your **home network**.

**Not** for use with Dropbox.

Dropbox is not meant for whole-PC backups, and the best way to do something like that would be to download [Dropbox's PC application](https://www.dropbox.com/install) and setup to only sync your "my_backup" folder, then copy all the contents of your hard drive in there (provide you have enough space). After it's done remove "my_backup" from the selective sync so you don't have to keep two copies of your data on your hard drive.

**Example of Selective Sync**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Insane for your quick reply. Yes, I have installed Dropbox's PC Application.Now how can I setup sync to my_backup folder.

Comment: I can't find any preference option neither on my local drive nor on dropbox drive on net. :(

Comment: I have found this dialogue box. But there is no Advance option.:( . Sorry I don't know how to show pic on this comment box :(

Comment: I installed that just two days ago. And the soft is updated shown on the box :)

Comment: Yahoo!!! I've got it. It's under Account tab. Thanks...thanks ....and thanks so much @Insane. You helped me much :)

Comment: I was just about to post and say it's under the accounts tab, hah. Glad I could help.